# Multidimensional arrays through functions (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Complete beginner here.

If I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
$main_array = array(
$sub_array1('name','value1','value2'),
$sub_array2('name','value1','value2'),
$sub_array3('name','value1','value2')
);
```

...and a user function:

```
function multiply($a, $b) {
$result = $a * $b};
return $result;
};
```

What's the best method to loop each sub-array through the function such that $a is value1 and $b is value2? How can I get the outcome to look something like:

Name1: result1

Name2: result2

Name3: result3

I'm currently fiddling with the following:

```
foreach($main_array as $x) {
print_r(multiply($x['value1'], $x['value2']));
};
```

...which is wrong in syntax, logic, or both.

Comment: that array is not valid

Comment: Thanks for the correction; the $ was a typo. The way I have it right now is how Nick Marden had commented below.

Answer (score 0):

print_r will display a readable version of a variable, such as an object, array etc. Since you are looping through an array to display a value in a certain format - this will not work.

To get the intended result, a simple change is required:

```
foreach($main_array as $x) {

    echo $x['name'] . multiply($x['value1'], $x['value2']);

};
```

Or ditch the user defined function 'multiply' for basic maths.

```
foreach($main_array as $x) {

    echo $x['name'] . ($x['value1'] * $x['value2']);

};
```

**Edit:**

Also to Dagon's point above in the comments - the array you are using is not valid. The syntax is wrong and you aren't using named keys but you are referencing them. Change the structure like so:

```
$name = "Value";
$value = 10;    

$main_array = array(
        array('name' => $name, 'value1' => $value, 'value2' => $value),
        array('name' => $name, 'value1' => $value, 'value2' => $value),
        array('name' => $name, 'value1' => $value, 'value2' => $value),
    );
```

Alternatively if you wanted to make it a bit more readable.

```
$nameValue = "test";
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$subArray1 = [
        "name" => $nameValue,
    "value1" => $value1,
    "value2" => $value2
];

$subArray2 = [
    "name" => $nameValue,
    "value1" => $value1,
    "value2" => $value2
];

$subArray3 = [
    "name" => $nameValue,
    "value1" => $value1,
    "value2" => $value2
];

$main_array = array($subArray1, $subArray2, $subArray3);
```

**Updated for more completeness & assuming use of user function multiply**

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: name` & `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function multiply()`

Comment: And where are all these `$nameValue` `$value1` etc coming from

Comment: @RiggsFolly - see edit, also assuming the use of the original posters multiply function.

Comment: I am going on the assumption that he intends to do more in the multiply function - hence why I left his user function in the code.

Comment: Oh you must have a get out of jail free card

Comment: @NickMarden Thanks for the help! How you set up the arrays is exactly how I actually set it up; I just screwed up the transposing when I was posting here because I wanted to keep the example simple. Indeed, as you say, the multiply function is simply an example. The one I need to pass through is more complex. I will give your foreach() a try, thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: Works like a charm. Thanks, everyone, for the help!

Comment: Not a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

First your array creation is incorrect

```
$main_array = array(
                    array('fred','1','2'),
                    array('bill','3','4'),
                    array('jane','5','6')
);
```

Now this array can be processed like this and the sub arrays which are not associative arrays and therefore are not name->value types have to be processed using their indexes

```
foreach ( $main_array as $sub_array ) {
    echo $sub_array[0] , ' = ' . ($sub_array[1] * $sub_array[2]);
}
```

And will produce the output:

```
fred = 2
bill = 12
jane = 30
```

> Note: `print_r()` is used to display arrays & onjects, you need to use `echo` or `print` to display scalar values.
>
> Also there is no `multiply` function, just use old fashioned maths eg `$x * $y`

Comment: Yes, the $ in the sub_array was a typo, thanks for the correction. The multiply function is just an example, what I am currently building takes the arguments and basically (100-abs($form_answer1-$a)) + (100-abs($form_answer2-$b)). Regardless, how would you get the sub-array's values to pass through such a function?